# Radeon 5500 with a Samsung monitor - not getting a full screen?

Tags: windows-7, graphics-card, hdmi, amd-radeon

I am running a Windows 7 machine, with an ATI Radeon HD 5500, and a Samsung SyncMaster P2370MS Monitor. When I use a VGA cable, everything is working fine. But when I use HDMI, the picture is centered, not appearing on the full screen. The whole picture looks a bit squished. I have spent HOURS looking through the monitor settings, updated the driver, googled the problem, and I'm getting nothing.

Comment: I had this issue with a Radeon 4890 and a Samsung TV. For nearly year I lived with it and then one day out of the blue the issue resolved itself with the 10.09 or 10.10 Catalyst drivers (I forget which).

Comment: Actually it was the 10.8 drivers as I remember the following line in the [release notes](http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/catalyst_108_release_notes.pdf) **HDMI default refresh rate now appears properly as 60 Hz under HDTV in Catalyst™ Control Center** as an aside i am still using the 10.8 drivers

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Enabling GPU scaling should solve the problem.

1. Open Catalyst Control Center
2. Select **Desktops and Display**
3. At the bottom, click the little
   arrow on the upper right corner of
   the selected monitor and click
   **Configure**

[image]

In that screen make sure "scale image to full panel size" is selected and GPU scaling is enabled

[image]

If that doesn't solve your problem click **Scaling Options** at the same screen and scroll the slider to the rightmost.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This seems like the driver restricts resolution output over HDMI and the monitor adjusts accordingly.  I would either 1)accept what it's doing 2)play with resolutions and refresh rates 3)change the monitor 4)go with VGA